# log4j RollingFileAppender create new files

Tags: log4j

How can i configure my rolling fileappender to create a new
log file after the old log files size is 10MB.

No log file should get deleted.

```
log.log
log2.log
log3.log
.....
```

My configuration now is:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

But there is always just one file and one backup file. 
I dont want any file to get replaced. When one log file
is full just create another log file and continue writing
into the new file.

How can i configure that?

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same problem do you found the solution and my maxbackupindex is 20 even getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

MaxBaackupIndex represents number of backup files required. if your requirement is 3 backup files, set maxBackUpIndex = 3. you can total 4 files log.log, log.1.log, log.2.log, log.3.log

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same problem do you found the solution and my maxbackupindex is 20 even getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set **append = false**. With **append=true**, it writes to the same file at the end of the file.